# Force lowercase content/HTML of contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

Is there a fix to allow `autocapitalize='off'` on `contenteditable` divs instead of using input fields?

I've been trying it out in Javascript with attributes and spellchecks, but nothing seems to fix my problem. If I apply a rule such as `text-transform: lowercase`, this will make the text you type lowercase, but the actual HTML value is still uppercase (where applicable).

How do I ensure it is all lowercase?

Comment: use `text-tranform:lowercase`

Comment: @GauravAggarwal yes, but the *value* (err HTML content) of that DIV will still be *capitalized*

Comment: mark use css as important `text-tranform:lowercase!important`

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Please read carefully my comment. Again.

Comment: @OwenAyres Read my comment carefully. Again: http://jsbin.com/semiqap/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan True - Original question did not specify a preference and the css-only solution may have been all that was needed. Nonetheless, have updated it to make that clearer. Thanks

Comment: @GauravAggarwal thanks for the answer but I only want the first letter to be lowercase, not the entire div.

Answer (score 1):

On contenteditable `blur` or `focusout` you could replace the content to lowercase:

```js
var editable = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable]');

function toLower(){
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
}

[].forEach.call(editable, function(el){
  el.addEventListener("focusout", toLower);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable>THis is some Sample Capital Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform).

```css
div {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>here is the text</div>
```

Comment: using CSS styles does not change the actual element content/value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution -

Use CSS to blind the JS effect for user-

```
*[contenteditable]{
    text-transform:lowercase;
}
```

Then,

1. With Native JS-

   JS-

   ```
   function changeCase(id){
       var txt = document.getElementById(id);
       txt.innerText = txt.innerText.toLowerCase()
   }
   ```

   HTML-

   ```
   <div contenteditable onBlur="changeCase('myId')" id="myId">This is Camelcase Text. Type something on me to see effects</div>
   ```
2. With Jquery-

   JS-

   ```
   $('[contenteditable]').on('blur',function(e){
       $(this).text($(this).text().toLowerCase());
   });
   ```

   HTML-

   ```
   <div contenteditable>This is Camelcase Text. Type something on me to see effects</div>
   ```

Comment: This question is **not tagged jQuery**. *"using native javascrpt"* seems therefore odd in your answer. Also the code you provided makes absolutely no sense; would you use it in a production environment? (To clarify, as soon you start typing... **what happens with the caret?**)

Comment: Hope this fix the issue in both ways ;)